# Is there ever any difference between adjusting ZonedDateTimes using the with* functions, TemporalAdjusters or by setting TemporalFields?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, dayofweek

Say I have the following code:

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime inputZonedDateTime = inputDate.toInstant().atZone(zoneId);
ZonedDateTime flattenedDateTime = inputZonedDateTime.withDayOfYear(1);
```

Oddly enough this utility method does not exists for weeks, so for weeks I implemented it like this:

```
flattenedDateTime = inputZonedDateTime.with(java.time.temporal.ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
```

And then you could also do this:

```
flattenedDateTime = inputZonedDateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
```

(which also isn't available for weeks)

Is there ever any difference between these 3 ways of adjusting the date? I want to make sure that they are **always** functionally equivalent so that I am sure I can use always them interchangeably for this specific scenario of adjusting a ChronoUnit to 1. Especially because there are no utility methods for the "week" case.

Comment: I am not quite sure about your Q. What is it exactly that you are looking for? @Sebastiaan van den Broek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion. The difference is not that the `withXx` methods work differently from the `TemporalAdjusters`. The difference is:

- The first day of the year and the first day of the month are unambiguously defined and therefore easy to build into either a `withXx` method or a temporal adjuster.
- The first day of the week differs by culture. In some places the week begins on Sunday or some other day. Setting `ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK` to 1 sets the day of week to Monday. So either of a `withFirstDayOfWeek` method or a `firstDayOfWeek` temporal adjuster would have been dangerous and would have given some users surprising results.

If you are sure that you want to consider only the ISO week, in which Monday is the first day, `inputZonedDateTime.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)` is fine for your purpose. Otherwise the correct solution is to use a `WeekFields` object and its `dayOfWeek​()` temporal field. Setting this field to 1 will set to the first day of the week according to the week definition that the `WeekFields` object represents.

According to Wikipedia:

- In much of the Middle East the week begins on Saturday.
- In Canada, United States, India, Japan, Taiwan, Hong Kong, Macau, Israel, Egypt, South Africa, the Philippines, and most of Latin America it begins on Sunday.
- EU and most of other European countries, most of Asia and Oceania use Monday (in agreement with ISO).

> I was trying to take into account that Sunday can be the first day of the week in for example the US.

Example code

```
    // Don’t set default locale from production code, it’s for demonstration only
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SD"));

    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    ZonedDateTime inputZonedDateTime
            = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 3, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Asia/Amman"));
    ZonedDateTime flattenedDateTime = inputZonedDateTime.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1);
    System.out.println("First day of week in "
            + Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH)
            + " is " + flattenedDateTime.format(formatter));
```

> First day of week in Sudan is Saturday, March 2, 2019, 12:00:00 PM

Of course you may obtain the correct locale for `WeekFields.of` some other way. Output with a couple of other locales includes:

- es-PY:

  > First day of week in Paraguay is Sunday, March 3, 2019, 12:00:00 PM
- mg-MG:

  > First day of week in Madagascar is Monday, February 25, 2019, 12:00:00 PM

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week)

Comment: Around 96% of cultures( >98% of worlds population)  uses ISO or non ISO calendars that define a 7  day long week, therefore same numbering system is used for representation of days in a week. @Ole V.V.

Comment: This is good to know, because I was trying to take into account that Sunday can be the first day of the week in for example the US. But I would hope that would still work correctly if my timezone is set to a timezone in the US? Or should I take additional steps?

Comment: Ok, well unfortunately that means the system will need another setting if I cannot deduce it from the timezone. Users can have projects with various timezones and they would probably also want their week to start on the correct day. Looks like I need another field in my Project object.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I have added example code for how to adjust a datetime object to the first day of week in a way that respects a specific locale and its week definition.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with `ZonedDateTime flattenedDateTime = inputZonedDateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(wf.getFirstDayOfWeek()));` but yours looks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you question whether or not this is right approach for finding:

1. Get me zoned date-time with a date day-of-week adapted to be a Monday.

   Example: 05-03-2019 .... -> 04-03-2019 ....
2. Get me zoned date-time with a date adapted to be the first day of a month!

   Example: 05-03-2019 .... -> 01-03-2019 ....

### Then the answer is yes.

```
        ZoneId zoneID = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Belgrade" ) ;
        ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneID) ;

        System.out.println(zoneDateTime.withDayOfMonth(1));
        System.out.println(zoneDateTime.withMonth(1));
        System.out.println(zoneDateTime.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK,1));
        System.out.println(zoneDateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()));
```

Comment: I know I can find the dates like this and basic scenarios have been tested, I'm specifically trying to find out if there are any edge cases where there is difference in behavior.

Comment: Yes, they are always functionally equivalent for called cases of application. Java Time library has gone thru a lot of improvements and it's integritity is now not questionable at all.( of course using right approach like from above ) @SebastiaanvandenBroek